# Присвоение значения внешней переменной в теле функции

Tags: javascript

```
let i = 1;
function foo(a){
a = 2
}
foo(i)
console.log(i)
```

почему выводит 1?

Comment: ...а что должно? И почему

Comment: Ну я же присваиваю в функции значение 2

Comment: .........И что? ну ты присваиваешь в `a` значение

Answer (score 0):

В примере, Вы передаете аргументы функции. Когда функции передается переменная `i` в `foo(i)`, и значение переменной `i` (равное 1) копируется в параметр a функции `foo`.

Внутри функции `foo` происходит присвоение значения `a = 2`, но это **присвоение происходит с параметром** `a`, **а не с самой переменной** `i`. Поэтому, когда вы печатаете значение переменной `i` после вызова функции `foo`, значение остается неизменным (равным 1), так как изменения внутри функции не затрагивают значение исходной переменной `i`.

Comment: Несколько ваших последних ответов очень напоминают ответы от чата, только с прокачанным форматированием

Comment: Я не нейросеть, отвечаю только на то, что понимаю и как считаю правильным)